# Compiling error when insert pair into set

Tags: c++

I can't understand why g++ returns error like this:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_pair.h: In function 鈥榖ool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = int, _T2 = stop]鈥
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h:227:   instantiated from 鈥榖ool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = std::pair<int, stop>]鈥
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h:921:   instantiated from 鈥榮td::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = std::pair<int, stop>, _Val = std::pair<int, stop>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<std::pair<int, stop> >, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<int, stop> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<int, stop> >]鈥
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_set.h:321:   instantiated from 鈥榮td::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const _Key&) [with _Key = std::pair<int, stop>, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<int, stop> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<int, stop> >]鈥
newGraph.cpp:48:   instantiated from here
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_pair.h:104: error: no match for 鈥榦perator<鈥in 鈥榑_x->std::pair<int, stop>::second < __y->std::pair<int, stop>::second鈥
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <list>

#include <set>
#include <utility> // for pair
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

const int max_weight = INT_MAX;

struct stop {
    std::string name_stop;
    int id_stop;
    bool operator !=(const stop &rhs) const
    {
        return ((id_stop != rhs.id_stop) || (name_stop != rhs.name_stop));
    }

};

struct neighbor {

    stop target;
    int weight;
    neighbor(stop arg_target, int arg_weight) : target(arg_target), weight(arg_weight) { }
};

std::list<stop> dijkstraComputeAndGetShortestPaths(stop src,
                                            stop dst,
                                            std::vector< std::vector<neighbor> > &adj_list,
                                            std::vector<int> &min_distance,
                                            std::vector<stop> &previous)
{
    stop fake_stop;
    fake_stop.id_stop = INT_MAX;
    fake_stop.name_stop = "Null";

    std::list<stop> path;
    int n = adj_list.size();
    min_distance.clear();
    min_distance.resize(n, max_weight);
    min_distance[src.id_stop] = 0;
    previous.clear();
    previous.resize(n, fake_stop);
    std::set< std::pair< int, stop > > vertex_queue;
    vertex_queue.insert(std::make_pair(min_distance[src.id_stop], src));

    while (!vertex_queue.empty()) 
    {
        int dist = vertex_queue.begin()->first;
        stop u = vertex_queue.begin()->second;
        vertex_queue.erase(vertex_queue.begin());

        // Visit each edge exiting u
        const std::vector<neighbor> &neighbors = adj_list[u.id_stop];

        for(std::vector<neighbor>::const_iterator neighbor_iter = neighbors.begin();
            neighbor_iter != neighbors.end();
         neighbor_iter++)
        {
            stop v = neighbor_iter->target;
            int weight = neighbor_iter->weight;
            int distance_through_u = dist + weight;

            if (distance_through_u < min_distance[v.id_stop]) {
                vertex_queue.erase(std::make_pair(min_distance[v.id_stop], v));

                min_distance[v.id_stop] = distance_through_u;
                previous[v.id_stop] = u;
                vertex_queue.insert(std::make_pair(min_distance[v.id_stop], v));

            }

        }
        if(u.id_stop == dst.id_stop)
        {
            std::cout << "Find : ";
            for ( ; dst != fake_stop; dst = previous[dst.id_stop])
            {
                path.push_front(dst);
            }

            return path;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::vector< std::vector<neighbor> > adj_list(9);
    stop stop_s;
    stop_s.id_stop = 1001;
    stop_s.name_stop = "A";

    stop stop_x;
    stop_x.id_stop = 1002;
    stop_x.name_stop = "B";

    adj_list[stop_s.id_stop].push_back(neighbor(stop_x, 5));

    stop_s.id_stop = 1003;
    stop_s.name_stop = "C";

    adj_list[stop_x.id_stop].push_back(neighbor(stop_s, 15));

    stop_x.id_stop = 1004;
    stop_x.name_stop = "D";

    adj_list[stop_s.id_stop].push_back(neighbor(stop_x, 20));

    stop_s.id_stop = 1001;
    stop_s.name_stop = "A";

    std::vector<int> min_distance;
    std::vector<stop> previous;

    std::list<stop> path = dijkstraComputeAndGetShortestPaths(stop_s, stop_x, adj_list, min_distance, previous);
    std::cout << "Distance from 1001 to 1004: " << min_distance[stop_x.id_stop] << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Path : ";
    #if 0
    for (int index = 0; index < path.size(); index++)
    {
        auto path_front = path.begin();
        std::advance(path_front, index);

        std::cout << path_front->id_stop << " ";

    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using libstdc++ 4.1? That's ancient..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::set` require you to specify an `operator <` for the type it holds or you can supply your own comparison functor as a template parameter.  Since `stop` does not have an `operator <` the `operator <` from `std::pair` is not compileable since it relies on using the `operator <` of the types it holds..  You either need to supply your own comparison functor or define an `operator <` for `stop`.

Comment: I added operator < now it is OK.